# JQuery: iterate for same Class Name

Tags: jquery

I have several div with same class name. But have different content. They are like as follows

```
  <div class="schoolLib">
         <div class="message">
            <span class="msgTextLib">This is a sample text.</span>
         </div>
  </div>


  <div class="schoolCanteen">
         <div class="message">
            <span class="msgTextcanteen">This is another sample text.</span>
         </div>
  </div>


  <div class="schoolBus">
         <div class="message">
            <span class="msgTextBus">This is a sample text for Bus.</span>
         </div>
  </div>
```

How can I get all text inside div of message class using .html(). My contents are coming dynamically. I have different span class. Also I need to set different text for all div using .html(). So I need a way to get all contents under class name message iteratively. I konw about .each() method but don't know how to do this. As a beginner I need your help. I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Way too basic, please use Google on how to use `.each()`. Also here is the jQuery doc...http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each` to iterate over the collection:

```
$('.message').each(function(){
    var msg = $(this);
    msg.html('<div> new content </div>'); //for adding html
    //or to set the text use
    msg.text('change text');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comment pointed out use .each() to get the content. Just for your reference posting the snippet.

```
    var html = '';
    $('.message').each(function(){
      html += $(this).html(); //get the html
      $(this).html('<span>something else</span>') //set a different html
    });
    console.log(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you always have just one span for each message:

$('.message').each(function(){

alert($(this).children().first().text());

});

I don't know what you want to do with the messages content, but with this you can get all of them. 
If you want you can store them in an array and use in other context...